# how to make def (sequence) in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm a beginner. I have a question. 
There is a list [3, 2, 8, 5, 44, 9].
How do I make a `def SortMe(sequence)`?

I want the result to be [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 44]

Answer (score 3):

You'll want the sort method on [Collection](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) in groovy. It's got lots of fun options.

```
def list = [2, 5, 7, 1, 4, 3].sort()
println list
```

Welcome to groovy. Hope you like it.

Comment: :)))))! That`s not what i mean. I need to write a def. it suppose to look like def sortMe (sequence) {.......................}

Answer (score 0):

kingObergers is right on how to sort a Collection...

However, if you want to wrap it in a function, you can do:

```
Collection sortMe( Collection a ) {
  a.sort( false )
}

def listA =  [3, 2, 8, 5, 44, 9]
def listB = sortMe( listA )

assert listA == [3, 2, 8, 5, 44, 9] // Original is unchanged
assert listB == [2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 44] // Sorted list is returned from sortMe
```

Passing `false` to the sort method means that a new sorted collection will be returned, and the original Collection will remain unchanged

Comment: I'v been told it suppose to iterate through the list with method .each

Comment: @Alex If you have a lot of arbitrary rules you are supposed to be following, don't you think you should let us know what they are in the question, rather than keeping them a secret and hoping we somehow work them out?

Comment: sorry guys :) it seems like this task is a pain in the ass :)

Comment: @Alex It may not be.  And it may be a good way of learning sorting.  But if you don't tell us the restrictions you've been given, we're just going to tell you to use the `sort` method.

Comment: Understood! No more arbitrary rules!

Answer (score 0):

another solution is instead of use a list use a TreeSet

def list = [10,10,1] as TreeSet

this is the output: 1,10

you get a list ordered and without duplicates.